# Using a Returned Value in a SQL Function to Replace the current value

Tags: mysql, sql, function, variables, set

**I'm retrieving the maximum salary value but I can't get it to replace the employee's current salary value. I haven't successfully written out the 'SET' command which I think would be necessary**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION f_max_salary (p_emp_no INTEGER) RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

DECLARE v_max_salary DECIMAL(10,2);

SELECT
    MAX(s.salary)
INTO v_max_salary

FROM
    salaries s
        JOIN
    employees e ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no;

RETURN v_max_salary;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: If you need to replace the employees current salary then you need to UPDATE see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html. You could improve this question by providing sample data and expected outcome as text. NB your function looks logically wrong

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to test your function first with several values. It looks to me like you are not filtering by the employee ID.

Thanks,
Kathi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).